# Java - Synchronized block works differently than method

Tags: java, critical-section

I am trying to figure out, what the difference between a synchronized block  and a synchronized function actually is. This Code works perfectly, as it avoids mistakes in the critical section

```
class ThreadSynchronous extends Thread {
static int m_count = 0;
String s;

ThreadSynchronous(String s) {
    this.s = s;
}

public void run() {
    synchronized (getClass()) {
        ...
    }
}
}

public class ThreadExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new ThreadSynchronous("Thread1: ");
    Thread t2 = new ThreadSynchronous("Thread2: ");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try{
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
    }
}
}
```

But if I use `public synchronized void run()` instead, it doesn't work equally/properly.

Comment: Nope, indeed it won't. In one case you're synchronizing on the class object, in the other case on the instance. And you are using a `static m_count`, so synchronizing on an instance won't work.

Comment: Notice that non-static `synchronized` methods synchronize on `this`. What you have implemented is effectively what a `static synchronized` method does: it synchronizes on the `class` object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the [JLS 8.4.3.6. synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used.
>
> For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was invoked) is used.

In the `synchronized (getClass())` block you synchronize on the `Class` object, thus all instances of `ThreadSynchronous` are serialized.

When you make the *instance method* `synchronized`, you are synchronizing only on that instance (the `this` reference).

Comment: in other words `public void synchronized foo() { // } ` is similar to `public void foo () { synchronized(this) { // } }`

Comment: Thank you, it makes perfect sense. I accomplished the same "improper"-behavior , using this-reference instead of getClass().

Answer (score 2):

The two synchronize on different objects.

`synchronized (getClass()) { ... }` synchronizes on the class, so of your two Thread instances, only one at a time can enter the block.

On the other hand, `public synchronized void run() { ... }` synchronizes on the instance, so both of the two instances can enter the block in parallel. Only if a single instance were shared by multiple threads, then this block would allow only one of them to execute.

Synchronized methods synchronize on the instance for normal instance methods, and on the class object for static methods.

So, if your `run()` method could be refactored to become a static one, then the `synchronized` method keyword would give you the `synchronized (getClass()) { ... }` behaviour.